# Could someone explain this typescript syntax to me?

Tags: typescript

This is a function declaration I'm looking at:

```
const createStore = (
  rootReducer: Reducer, 
  initialState: State, 
  errorToAction: (e: Error) => AnyAction | null = generateActionFromError
): ReturnType<typeof createStore> => {...}
```

And a helper function that returns an action creator:

```
const generateActionFromError = (e: Error): AnyAction | null => {...}
```

I'm wondering what that last parameter means?

The

```
errorToAction: (e: Error) => AnyAction | null = generateActionFromError
```

I understand the first piece, that `errorToAction` is a function that takes an argument `e` or type `Error` and after that is where my understanding of the syntax becomes unclear.

Comment: `callbackName: (paramName: ParamType) => ReturnType = defaultCallbackValue`

Comment: Followup - is there a way to extract that logic out to its own variable? Instead of having it defined as a function parameter?

Comment: what do you mean "extract that logic"?

Answer (score 3):

```
errorToAction: (e: Error) => AnyAction | null = generateActionFromError
```

You got the first part, which is that errorToAction is a parameter whose type is function that has the following signature

```
(e: Error) => AnyAction | null
```

This signature means that the function takes one argument of type Error and return a value of type AnyAction | null. Which means that it can either return a value of type AnyAction or it can return null.

The "| null" part has effect only when strictNullChecks is true in Typescript compiler options. When strictNullChecks, all types allow null or undefined making "| null" or "| undefined" unnecessary.

```
= generateActionFromError
```

The last part is the default value for the parameter errorToAction. Meaning if someone calls createStore and omits the 3rd parameter, the value of the parameter is will be generateActionFromError